# Mellanox connectX-2 - compatibility

Tags: networking, 10gbethernet, sfp, hpe

We want to upgrade our network to 10Gbits.
On eBay you find a lot of old HP Mellanox connectX-2 SFP+ cards which are capable of 10Gbit/s.
We want to give our server one of them and connect it to a HPE OfficeConnect 1950 Switch which is also capable of SFP+ 10Gbit/s.

Now I read that you've to make sure that the SFP+ devices are compatible with each other, but I don't find any information about that devices.

Do you know if they're compatible or where I can find this information? Or are any HPE devices in general are compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are good cheap 10GbE adapters.

Your best option is to use DAC cables if the run is short enough. If you *need* to use fiber, then just use HP-spec Multimode SFP+ modules.

An inexpensive source for what you need is FiberStore - http://fs.com

Compatible DAC cables: http://www.fs.com/products/36784.html

Compatible SFP+ modules: http://www.fs.com/products/11559.html

Compatible fiber: http://www.fs.com/products/41730.html

Comment: Thank you so much :)

This are passive cables, does the HP switch support such passive cables or does it need an active one?

Comment: I listed the compatible components above.

Comment: Thanks, I only want to make sure if all is right :)
Only for interest: Does every HP switch support passive and active DACs?

Comment: Are you sure that the DAC cable is supported? The one you send me is the HPE J9281B which isn't listed in the datasheet. Only the JD096C ones. The optic module J9150A is listed there. Or is it better to buy this one: http://www.fs.com/products/36787.html Or are there no differences